# Unable to put manuals open at Emacs directly from terminal

Tags: emacs, manuals

I want to open manuals directly in Terminal to Emacs by

```
man man
```

I put the following code as an alias in .zshrc unsuccessfully

```
alias man=x
unalias man  
man() { emacs ^x man }
```

**How can you open manuals to emacs?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you mean:

```
function man() { emacs -eval "(progn (setq Man-notify-method 'bully) (man \"$1\"))" }
```

The `setq` is there just to make the manual page hide the `*scratch*` buffer; if you don't want that, it is enough to do

```
function man() { emacs -eval "(man \"$1\")" }
```

If you want to call Emacs functions from the command line, you must write the function call in elisp; you can't just give Emacs key sequences on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I completely understand your question, but you can open a man page in emacs by simply doing `M-x man` followed by the man page you want to view. If you want to do this directly from the command line I imagine it would not be too difficult to set up a script to do this.

Answer (score 1):

```
alias man 'emacs -e man'
```

Check out [this](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Initial-Options.html) part of the info pages (and the following sections) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

A few possibilities, depending on how you want the man pages formatted:

```
man man > /tmp/man
emacs /tmp/man
```

or

```
zcat `man -w man` | nroff > /tmp/man
emacs /tmp/man
```

or

```
emacs `man -w man`
```